# ¿Cómo evitar el uso de eval para saber si una variable existe?

Tags: javascript, select

¡Hola!

Estoy intentando hacer un `SELECT` dinámico con un array asociativo con javascript. Para ello, he usado `eval` como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
eval("Provincias" + comunidadAutonoma.value);
```

Para saber si efectivamente existe la variable llamada ProvinciasAndalucia por ejemplo o ProvinciasCastillaLaMancha o cosas así, según el nombre de la comunidad elegida.

Pero he leído que el uso de `eval` es peligroso... ¿entonces qué otra forma hay?

De lo contrario, la única manera que se me ocurre no es tan dinámica... Con múltiples `if` (probablemente anidados) o un `switch` múltiple, lo que crearía muchísimas más líneas de código...

¿Hay alguna otra forma de sustituir la función `eval` para hacer lo mismo de modo seguro?

### ___

ACTUALIZACIÓN

### ___

Tengo los siguientes select:

```html
<select name="ComunidadAutonomaEnvio" id="ComunidadAutonomaEnvio">
                    <option value="Selecciona">- Selecciona -</option>
                    <option value="Andalucia">Andalucía</option>
                    <option value="Aragon">Aragón</option>
                    <option value="Cantabria">Cantabria</option>
                    <option value="CastillaLaMancha">Castilla-La Mancha</option>
                    <option value="CastillaYLeon">Castilla Y León</option>
                    <option value="Cataluna">Cataluña</option>
                    <option value="Ceuta">Ceuta</option>
                    <option value="ComunidadDeMadrid">Comunidad de Madrid</option>
                    <option value="ComunidadForalDeNavarra">Comunidad Foral de Navarra</option>
                    <option value="ComunidadValenciana">Comunidad Valenciana</option>
                    <option value="Extremadura">Extremadura</option>
                    <option value="Galicia">Galicia</option>
                    <option value="IslasBaleares">Islas Baleares</option>
                    <option value="IslasCanarias">Islas Canarias</option>
                    <option value="LaRioja">La Rioja</option>
                    <option value="Melilla">Melilla</option>
                    <option value="PaisVasco">País Vasco</option>
                    <option value="PrincipadoDeAsturias">Principado de Asturias</option>
                    <option value="RegionDeMurcia">Región de Murcia</option>
                </select>

<select name="ProvinciaEnvio" id="ProvinciaEnvio"></select>
<select name="LocalidadEnvio" id="LocalidadEnvio"></select>
```

Están vacíos porque tengo que cargarlos con javascript dinámicamente.

Los tengo enlazados con Javascript así:

```
var comunidadAutonoma = document.getElementById('ComunidadAutonomaEnvio');
var provincia = document.getElementById('ProvinciaEnvio');
var localidad = document.getElementById('LocalidadEnvio');
```

Tengo una variable que pretende ser un array asociativo así:

```
var ProvinciasAndalucia = {
        "Almeria" : "Almería",
        "Cadiz" : "Cádiz",
        "Cordoba" : "Córdoba",
        "Granada" : "Granada",
        "Huelva" : "Huelva",
        "Jaen" : "Jaén",
        "Malaga" : "Málaga",
        "Sevilla" : "Sevilla"
    };
```

Esto lo tengo para cada Comunidad autónoma.
Entonces lo que quería era que automáticamente añadiese la palabra "Provincias" al value del option seleccionado, compruebe que existe una variable que se llame así (que en este caso así es) y la use para crear  los option del select ProvinciaEnvio (o sea, usando la variable provincia). Es decir, de Andalucía, tendría que coger la variable ProvinciasAndalucía, de CastillaLaMancha, la variable ProvinciasCastillaLaMancha, etc...

Para evitar hacer un `switch` que evalúe cada una de las posibles comunidades autónomas y entonces decirle manualmente qué variable tiene que utilizar y qué  tiene que hacer. Por eso, como en teoría  no es seguro usar eval, quisiera saber qué otraforma  de hacerlo  hay.

¡Un saludo!

Comment: Realmente, ¿cuál es la comprobación que debes hacer? No queda muy claro, creo.

Comment: El `select` lo tengo en la variable ComunidadAutonoma. El `.value` hace referencia al valor del `option` seleccionado. Es decir, el nombre de la comunidad autónoma sin espacios ni tildes, como  podría  ser CastillaLaMancha o Andalucia. Tengo creada una variable llamada exactamente igual pero con la palabra  "Provincias" justo al principio, pegado a Por ejemplo, ProvinciasAndalucia. Lo que necesito comprobar es si existe esa  variable  para elegirla y crear con ella el  contenido del siguiente `SELECT` con los valores de las  provincias que correspondan.

Comment: ¿Pero por qué no usar una variable con propósito general...? Siento que sigo sin entender tu escenario, jeje. Perdona. Podría escribir una respuesta de por qué `eval` no es una buena práctica a seguir, pero puedo reproducir tu caso.

Comment: Justo lo que quiero es evitar el uso de eval. Pretendo NO tener que decirle a javascript "¿El valor del option seleccionado es Andalucia? Entonces rellena el select provincia con la variable ProvinciasAndalucia" (y así con cada provincia)... En cambio quisiera lo siguiente: "Añade al principio del valor del option seleccionado la palabra Provincias y, si existe una variable que se llame así, úsala para rellenar el select llamado  provincia". Pero como no es seguro eval, que básicamente en este caso me  decía si existe, quería saber si hay algo que me sirva para hacer la comprobación. ¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿Tienes todos los valores posibles guardados en variables? Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega esa información.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que más bien el problema es de diseño.
La *metaprogramación* es siempre algo a evitar y su uso debe ser justificado. Con eso no digo que no pueda usarse, hay implementaciones de *metaprogramación* muy útiles y escenarios donde simplifica el desarrollo muchísimo (por ejemplo, los `Proxy` de *JavaScript*), pero creo que este no es el caso.

Si bien tienes varias constantes ya definidas del tipo

```
var ProvinciasAndalucia = {
    "Almeria" : "Almería",
    "Cadiz" : "Cádiz",
    // ...
};
```

Nada te impide hacer un objeto donde almacenes toda esta información y aproveches los `value` de las `option` para indexarlo y poder sacar la información de forma segura.

```
const values = {
    Andalucia: {
        Almeria: 'Almería',
        Cadiz: 'Cádiz',
        // ...
    },
    CastillaLaMancha: {
        Guadalajara: 'Guadalajara',
        Toledo: 'Toledo',
        // ...
    },
    // ...
};
```

De este siempre podrás acceder a la información requerida de forma dinámica y segura.

```
comunidadAutonoma.addEventListener('change', event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    const provinces = values[value];

    // Provinces es, en este punto, el análogo a tu anterior objeto ProvinciasX
    // ...
});
```

De todas formas, deberíamos recurrir a la *metaprogramación* implementando algo parecido a `Object.keys(provinces)` para acceder a cada uno de los campos y su valor asociado.
Para ello, te propongo la siguiente estructura

```
const values = {
    Andalucia: [
        { 
            label: 'Almería',
            value: 'Almeria'
        },
        { 
            label: 'Cádiz',
            value: 'Cadiz'
        },
        // ...
    ],
    CastillaLaMancha: [
        {
            label: 'Guadalajara',
            value: 'Guadalajara'
        },
        {
            label: 'Toledo',
            value: 'Toledo'
        },
        // ...
    ],
    // ...
};
```

De este modo ya no nos hará falta acceder a las *keys*. Las *keys* debería ser algo que se conozca tanto en tiempo de desarrollo como en tiempo de compilación. De nuevo, siempre que sea posible y, evitar esta práctica debe estar justificado.

```
comunidadAutonoma.addEventListener('change', event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    const provinces = values[value];

    provinces.forEach(province => {
        // Create option html element based on 
        // province.label and province.value
    });
});
```

Y sí, en este trozo de código estoy accediendo a una clave dinámica que no se conoce en tiempo de desarrollo ni compilación, pero minimiza futuros accesos y deja un objeto (`values`) más limpio. De todas formas, `values` es un `map`, por lo que tampoco es tan mala práctica.

También creo que todo el objeto `values` merece ir a un *json* que cargues al levantar la *web*. De este modo no mezclas la implementación del código con los datos de éste.

---

El uso de accesos a claves dinámicas y, sobretodo el uso de `eval` no es peligroso en sí. *JavaScript* es un lenguaje totalmente dinámico y seguro (cuando se cumplen con los *guards* pertinentes). La desventaja del `eval` es la *performance*.
*JavaScript* es un lenguaje interpretado, el *parser* compila el código *JavaScript* a código máquina en *runtime*, lo que le llaman *Just in time compilation* (*JIT*), pero la mayoría de *engines* de *JavaScript* tienen un *preparser* y lo que le llaman las *hot functions* o *hot access* que guarda en memoria los accesos a funciones y sus tipos que más a menudo se usan (como si de una caché se tratara) para tener mayor velocidad de ejecución. Cualquier código que se encuentre dentro del `eval` es siempre ignorado por el *preparser* y nunca optimizado, sólo resuelto una y otra vez en *runtime* cada vez que debe ejecutarse. Para hacerse una idea, a ojos del *preparser*, todo aquello que esté dentro del `eval` es mero texto; sólo el *parser* lo resolverá.
Dejo [aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p-iiEDtpy6I&list=PLbu5I7PSOVlRFZHbCq9FRHVTlczwBYUYh&index=3&t=0s) un vídeo muy instructivo sobre todo este tema.

---

Por último, sigo dudando un poco sobre si esto es exactamente lo que preguntabas y esta respuesta resuelve tu escenario; no estoy del todo seguro.

En cualquier caso, espero que al menos haya podido divulgar un poco la mala práctica del `eval`.
Si, como digo, esta respuesta no se ajusta a tu pregunta, me lo comentas y encantado trataré de mejorarla.

---

**EDIT:** Añadir dinámicamente los `option`.

Primero, como ponía en los comentarios, todo el *json* podría añadir los datos de las localidades para cada una de las provincias. Podría ser simplemente una *property* más del objeto.

```
const values = {
    Andalucia: [
        { 
            label: 'Almería',
            value: 'Almeria',
            localidades: [
                { 
                    label: 'Mojácar',
                    value: 'Mojacar'
                },
                {
                    label: 'Roquetas de Mar',
                    value: 'Roquetas'
                }
            ]
        },
        // ...
    ], 
    // ...
};
```

Primero, dado que el objeto que mapea cada una de las opciones tiene esta estructura con `value` y `label`, podemos hacer una función que cree un *tag* `option` dado uno de estos objetos. Muy simple.

```
const createOption = obj => {
    const opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.setAttribute('value', obj.value);
    opt.innerHTML = obj.label;
    return opt;
}
```

Veíamos como podíamos suscribirnos al evento de cambio de valor de la comunidad autónoma y, de ahí, sacar la provincia

```
comunidad.addEventListener('change', event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    const provinces = values[value];
    updateProvinces(provinces);
});
```

Ahora, `updateProvinces` debe ser una función que, dado el *array* de provincias de la comunidad seleccionada, cree un `option` para cada una de ellas.

```
const updateProvinces = provinces => {
    cleanUpSelector(localidad);
    cleanUpSelector(provincia);

    provinces.forEach(p => {
        const option = createOption(p);
        provincia.appendChild(option);
    });
}
```

Antes de añadir los nuevos elementos `option` debemos eliminar los anteriores. En este caso también eliminamos las opciones del selector de localidades.
`cleanUpSelector` va a hacer eso, dado un selector cualquiera borrará su contenido y añadirá la opción *void* (la que he llamado la `IDLE_SELECTOR_VALUE`). En tu caso, tu `IDLE_SELECTOR_VALUE` era ese `Seleccionar`.

```
const cleanUpSelector = selector => {
    // Borramos el contenido del selector
    selector.innerHTML = '';

    // Añadimos la void option
    const idleSelectorOption = document.createElement('option');
    idleSelectorOption.setAttribute('value', IDLE_SELECTOR_VALUE)
    idleSelectorOption.innerHTML = '- Selecciona -';
    selector.appendChild(idleSelectorOption);
}
```

Análogamente podemos suscribirnos al evento de cambio de valor del selector de provincias para cambiar las opciones de las localidades. Muy similar.
La única diferencia notable es cómo obtenemos ese *array* de localidades, los datos.
Si bien `localidades` es un *array* propiedad del objeto provincia...

```
const getSelectedCom = _ => 
    comunidad.options[comunidad.selectedIndex].value;

const getSelectedProvince = value => {
    const provinces = values[getSelectedCom()];
    return provinces.find(p => p.value === value);
}
```

... obtenemos el valor de la comunidad autónoma seleccionada, obtenemos todas las provincias de ésta y filtramos aquella que tenga por valor el `value`, que es el valor seleccionado.
Todo este proceso puede hacerse de forma mucho más elegante teniendo algunas variables con esa información. Por ejemplo, la comunidad autónoma seleccionada o el *array* de provincias.

Por último, y dado que tenemos ese *void option*, debemos preocuparnos qué pasa cuando se selecciona esa opción. Para darte una idea, yo sólo borro todas las opciones en cascada, pero podrías implementar tu propia lógica para cada caso.

```
comunidad.addEventListener('change', event => {
    const { value } = event.target;

    if (value === IDLE_SELECTOR_VALUE) {
        cleanUpSelector(provincia);
        cleanUpSelector(localidad);
        return;
    }

    const provinces = values[value];
    updateProvinces(provinces);
});
```

En caso que en el selector de comunidad autónoma se seleccione ese valor, sólo borramos las opciones de localidad y provincia llamando a la función `cleanUpSelector`.
En el caso de la provincia, sólo borraríamos el selector de localidades.

Te dejo [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/d3wpu2s7/) el ejemplo completo.
Esta implementación es bastante *hand-made*, realmente. Con otros *frameworks* se haría sumamente más sencillo; con *jQuery* (por favor, no), *Angular*, *Vue*... cualquiera que tenga un *binding* de datos consistente entre la *vista* y el *code behind* (*[(ngModel)]*, *ngFor*, *v-for*, ...).

Espero que sirva.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Voy a probarlo ahora  mismo. Creo que sí es lo que quería...  Pruebo  y comento. Pero me queda  una duda... ¿Cómo hago para  el select de localidad según la provincia?  ¿Se le podría añadir ahí? ¿O sería por  ejemplo de esta forma? `const valuesLocalidad = {
  Almeria : [
   {
    label : "Abla",
    value : "Abla"
   },
   //...
  ],
  //...
 };` (Y también añadiendo "locations" al  estilo de  provinces que  se  llamase en el  evento change de provincia...) Yo creo que se trata de esto segundo, porque no  sé cómo se lo  podría añadir a la que tú me  has sugerido.

Comment: Del mismo modo podría hacerse. Expandir más el *set* `values` y añadir otro `eventListener` al `select` de provincias. Cuando el valor de las provincias cambie añades las `options` en el `select` de localidades basadas en el `value` de la provincia seleccionada. Con lo que te respondí es sencillo de hacer.

Comment: Para las provincias me ha funcionado  pefectamente... ¿con ampliar te refieres a algo así? `const values = {
  Andalucia: [
   {
    label: 'Almeria',
    value: 'Almería',
    localidades: [
     {
      label: 'Abra',
      value: 'Abra'
     },
     //...
    ]
   },
   // ...
  ],
  // ...
 };` Añadiendo también: `localidad.addEventListener('change', event => {
  const { value } = event.target;
  const locales = values.localidades[value];

  locales.forEach(local => {
   // Create option html element based on 
   // local.label and local.value
  });
 });` ¡Gracias!

Comment: Es un poco complicado leer el código en el comentario... Voy a ampliar un poco la respuesta.

Comment: ¡Estupendo! Me ha servido a la perfección! ¡Muchas gracias!